# Points not appearing on Time Series Graph in R

Tags: r, graph, time-series

I'm trying to plot a time series graph in R. Everything seems to be working (all my labels show up correctly and the axes are indexed how I want them to be, I just can't get any points to show up. My graph just looks completely blank.

Why is this happening?

My code is as follows:

```
forest <- c(0.096999565, 0.099238207, 0.101582401, 0.103624695, 0.105185874, 0.106321613, 0.107100639, 0.107698571, 0.108253954)

armenia.forest <- data.frame(forest)

plot.ts(armenia.forest, xlim = c(1992,2000), ylim = c(0.096999565,0.108253954), xlab = "Year", ylab = "Forest Land Per Capita", main = "Armenian Forest Land Over Time")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're plotting with `plot.ts`, you may want to make a time series object using `ts`.

```
forest <- c(
  0.096999565, 0.099238207, 0.101582401, 
  0.103624695, 0.105185874, 0.106321613, 
  0.107100639, 0.107698571, 0.108253954)

armenia.ts <- ts(forest, start = 1992, end = 2000)
```

Then you can plot more or less as you did:

```
plot.ts(armenia.ts, 
        xlim = c(1992,2000), 
        ylim = c(0.096999565,0.108253954), 
        xlab = "Year", 
        ylab = "Forest Land Per Capita", 
        main = "Armenian Forest Land Over Time",
        type = "p")
```

For an output like:

[image]

The reason you were getting a blank plot before was because of your `xlim` constraint- if you supply a non-time series object to `plot.ts`, it assumes the first item is 1, then 2, and so on. So, if you plot just the forest object but remove your `xlim` constraint you can get the same plot, just shifted to 1:9:

```
plot.ts(forest, 
        ylim = c(0.096999565,0.108253954), 
        xlab = "Year", 
        ylab = "Forest Land Per Capita", 
        main = "Armenian Forest Land Over Time",
        type = "p")
```

[image]